# Undefined Font Awesome Variable when @use

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome in my Laravel Project Sass files. I install via NPM:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Cool, I see it's installed in my `node_modules` and can see the `scss` folder is in there, everything looks good. I look at some examples of how people are including it in their Sass files and they're all using `@import`. If I use `@import` I see it also works as expected.

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";

.add-new {
    &:before {
        @include fa-icon;
        content: fa-content( $fa-var-plus );
    }
}
```

Looking at the Sass support [docs for `@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) though it says that it's discouraged:

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. **Prefer the @use rule instead.**

My problem is 2-fold:

1. This seems cumbersome. I'll be using Font Awesome throughout my project but to use it between files I need to remember to `@use` the two Font Awesome files:

```
    @use "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss" as *;
    @use "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss" as *;
```

2. **The above Sass code doesn't seem to work.** I get the error that `fa-content()` doesn't exist or `$fa-var-plus` doesn't exist. They don't seem to be accessible using the `@use` directive.

---

Since I'm new to many of these technologies ( Laravel, Sass, etc. ) I'm hoping for an informative answer that explains *why* this is happening and *what* a possible solution is. Presuming I want to follow the Sass warning and comply with using the `@use` directive. Maybe also explaining why/not this is advisable.

For future readers, I've brought up this issue with the [Font Awesome library](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2890). If you run into similar issues maybe air your concerns in their Github issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions out-of-order:

**Errors:**

Nothing here should be causing any obvious errors. That could have something to do with the version of Sass you are running, though. I don't have Laravel experience, but it looks to me like they assume Node Sass in their docs, which does not support the new module `@use` syntax. In order to uses the new syntax, you'll need to make sure you have Dart Sass instead. Dart Sass is the core implementation of Sass, and will always provide the most up-to-date features.

**Cumbersome:**

The goal of the new syntax is to make dependencies explicit and localized, so that does mean some additional overhead in many files. Still, there would be ways to simplify what you have. I recommend creating a local Sass file that contains two `@forward` rules -- basically merging those two npm imports into a single, local module:

```
// _fa.scss
@forward "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@forward "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
```

Now you can load that single local file wherever you need font-awesome, and it will forward both the npm files:

```
@use "fa" as *;

.add-new {
    &:before {
        @include fa-icon;
        content: fa-content( $fa-var-plus );
    }
}
```

Note that the `.scss` extensions and `_` prefixes are not required for Sass import paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer & ideas! TIL of `@forward`. It absolutely could be Node Sass but many of these errors originate in `sass.dart.js` so maybe Dart Sass. I have sass-loader as a dependency and I'm using [laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/css-preprocessors) to compile via their sass() method. I think in this case it may be a package issue. Both files import a `variables` file and I can't `@forward` when it runs into duplicated (actual) variables. So maybe the solution isn't fixing it form my end but trying to get them to update into better practices? In any case thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, getting them to update internally would help, but I don't think you have to wait. It's possible you could use the `show` or `hide` keywords in your forwards, or just prefix one of them with `as`, so that the variables aren't duplicated. `@forward "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid" as xxx-*;` might do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was the solution:

```
// scss/1-globals/_fa.scss
@forward "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@forward "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid" as fas-*; // Prefixed to prevent conflicts

// scss/3-components/_my-component.scss
@use "1-globals/fa" as *;

.button {
    
    &:before {
        @extend %fa-icon; // Base Font Awesome Styles
        @extend .fas;     // FA Type (far, fas, fab)
        content: fa-content( $fa-var-plus ); // Function to pull in icon
    }
    
}
```

Mirian was a huge help in this, so thanks! This is an issue I don't feel is well documented yet and I'll likely ask follow up questions in new topics.

Comment: Thank you and Miriam, I wouldn't have a chance to resolve this. But it means to use `@use …` in every file I want to include a FontAwesome Icon, right? Not so pretty thought…